# SmartPy: How to test an invalid transaction sent from a contract call

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I am testing a contract in SmartPy that uses a contract call (similar to the Collatz example).

Contract 'A' sends a transaction to contract 'B' with some data.
Contract 'B' does some computation and sends data back to contract 'A' including a parameter `validState`.
Contract 'A' receives the data from contract 'B' and does some verification including:

```
        sp.verify(params.validState == True)
```

Now, I am trying to write a test scenario in which `validState` is false, and so contract 'A' should fail the operation.

The problem is that since the first transaction from Contract 'A' to 'B' is valid, I cannot use the normal `valid = False` flag in the first transaction.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sadly not supported yet in the interpreter.
It's a known limitation and it's pretty high on the priority list.

You can often test each contract independently (far from perfect, obviously).